# Independence of column vectors in a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have three column vector `[1, 1, 2] ; [2, 2, 5]; [3, 3, 8]`.

The columns are not linear combinations of other columns but the first two rows are same.

Why are the column dependent? How does having same/dependent rows impact on the dependent of columns?

Comment: $2v_2-v_1=v_3$.  The third column is a linear combination of the first two.

Answer (score 2):

A possible explanation is: note that the first two coordinates of the vectors are the same: $[1,1]$, $[2,2]$ and $[3,3]$, that is, their difference is zero. It means that they satisfy the plane equation $x_1-x_2=0$. Every three vectors in a 2-dimensional space must be linearly dependent.

Another possible explanation: the matrix columns are linearly dependent iff the determinant is zero. It is zero as the matrix has two parallel rows.

Comment: Can explain more on the first reason. (I understand the second one, but it provides less to no intution however.)

Comment: The first explanation provides good geometric intuition.  If the vectors were linearly independent, they would span all of a three-dimensional space, but they all live in a two-dimensional subspace, therefore, the best that they could do is to span a two-dimensional space.  A two dimensional space is spanned by two vectors and not three, so at least one vector is unnecessary.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia The second method has a geometrical intuition too. A matrix determinant is related to the signed volume via the [triple scalar product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Properties). Thus determinant is nonzero iff the three vectors span a nonzero volume.

Comment: How did you calculate the plane $x_1-x_2$?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia The first two coordinates for all three vectors are the same: $[1,1]$, $[2,2]$, $[3,3]$. It makes their difference, that is the first coordinate minus the second coordinate, be zero. It is exactly $x_1-x_2=0$.

Comment: @A.G. How you wrote the plane equation confused me. How can a plane be defined by two variables?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Oh, I see. The plane equation has, in fact, all three variables: $1\cdot x_1-1\cdot x_2+0\cdot x_3=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The columns are dependent.

Note that

$\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    2  
    \end{array} \right]  - 2\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    2 \\
    2 \\
    5  
    \end{array} \right] + \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    3 \\
    3 \\
    8  
    \end{array} \right] = \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0  
    \end{array} \right]$